# How to clear MediaPlayer's cache in an UWP application?

Tags: uwp

In my UWP application, I have a MediaPlayer. When switch its source, I find that the previous video has some residual fragment. To solve this issue, a solution is to clear the MediaPlayer's cache when switching. But I did not find this kind of interface.

### More

I make a demo with below GitHub link. I used Nico's suggestion to call MediaSource's Dispose() function. But as you could see, when switch between MainPage and VideoPage1, the video residual fragment issue still exists.

### More 2

I paste my code as below. The test should be done via switching between MainPage and VideoPage1, back and forth. Then you could see the video residual fragment phenomenon.

But as I comment out, if we set the Source twice, then the vide residual fragment phenomenon does not exist, why?

Any other official solution?

```
mMediaPlayer.Source = ms;
mMediaPlayer.Source = ms;
```

Test code:

```
public sealed partial class VideoPage1 : Page
{
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    MediaSource ms;
    public static int count;

    public VideoPage1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        if (count % 2 == 0)
            ms = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/1.mp4"));
        else
            ms = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/2.mp4"));

        // One solution: if we set Source twice, then 
        // the vide residual fragment phenomenon does not exist, but why?
        // mMediaPlayer.Source = ms;
        mMediaPlayer.Source = ms;
        mMediaPlayer.Play();

        VideoObj.SetMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        mMediaPlayer.Pause();
        ms.Dispose();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

https://github.com/tomxue/Video_residual_fragment_issue

Answer (score 1):

> How to clear MediaPlayer's cache in an UWP application?

Please check this document. [`MediaSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource?view=winrt-19041) contains [`Dispose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource.dispose?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Media_Core_MediaSource_Dispose) that use to releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources. Before you switch to another source please invoke it manually. it will clear previous video's residual fragment.

Comment: Hi Nico, thank you for your reply! Please check my main post. I applied your method but failed to solve the issue. And a github demo code is provided.

Answer (score 0):

For clearing medial players, you should clear ResourceByteRangeOffset and ResourceByteRangeLength from args this document help you [Adaptive streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/adaptive-streaming)